# JQuery toggle off burger button on both window & button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I made a side bar with html & css to be shown per burger button click. toggling on/off works okay only via burger button click OR only outside window click. I want it to be toggled off whether user clicked on burger button or any place on the rest of the screen within the web page.

below is the JQuery snippet I am using:

```
//button id in html is #check
//button only toggle on/off
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#check').on("click",function(event) {
        if ($(event.target).closest("#check").length === 0) {
              $("#check").prop("checked", false);
        }
  });
});
```

OR this

```
//button id in html is #check
//window only toggle on/off
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click",function(event) {
        if ($(event.target).closest("#check").length === 0) {
              $("#check").prop("checked", false);
        }
  });
});
```

I want a modification to the code that combines both functionalities. I had no luck finding the proper way on my own.

Comment: So you want the sidebar to close when the user clicks on anything that isn't the sidebar itself?

Comment: no. If clicked on burger button (OR) if clicked anywhere on the screen. (if you mean the sidebar that will show up after first click then yes that logic works too)

Comment: So basically if they click anywhere on the screen. The burger button addition really isn't needed if you are also looking for ANYWHERE on the screen.  Just use the document click event handler and add the close script in there, no if statements or anything else needed.

Comment: I am not familiar with JQuery as of writing it. I barely understand it. would you provide me with the proper syntax? thanks in advance. I modified my previous reply, i misunderstood you the first time.